# MrJob on Hadoop can't import libraries

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera-cdh, mrjob

I am using CDH 5.7.2 and MrJob to submit a MapReduce job

When I try in **localmode, everything works fine**, but when i use `-r hadoop` It gives me following error:

```
 Task Id : attempt_1471071791922_0005_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I figured out that **problem occurs** when I try to import library:

```
import geopy
from geopy.distance import great_circle
```

This is how I execute my script:

```
python test2.py -r hadoop hdfs:///user/dataset/test_data --hadoop-streaming-jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar
```

P.S. MrJob cant fine hadoop-streaming-jar , so I specify it manually

How can I execute MapReduce jon on Hadoop **with library import** ?

Comment: try to add one more paramater during execution  -libjars /pathtoyour3rdpartylib

Comment: I'm not sure I have any python libraries as jar files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by myself.

What I have to do - is to install this library on **all of my nodes** (not just on master)